# R - preserve order when using matching operators (%in%)

Tags: r, operators

I am using matching operators to grab values that appear in a matrix from a separate data frame. However, the resulting matrix has the values in the order they appear in the data frame, not in the original matrix.  Is there any way to preserve the order of the original matrix using the matching operator?

Here is a quick example:

```
vec=c("b","a","c"); vec

df=data.frame(row.names=letters[1:5],values=1:5); df

df[rownames(df) %in% vec,1]
```

This produces `> [1] 1 2 3` which is the order `"a" "b" "c"` appears in the data frame. However, I would like to generate `>[1] 2 1 3` which is the order they appear in the original vector.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `match`.

```
df[match(vec, rownames(df)), ]
# [1] 2 1 3
```

Be aware that if you have duplicate values in either `vec` or `rownames(df)`, `match` may not behave as expected.

**Edit:**
I just realized that row name indexing will solve your issue a bit more simply and elegantly:

```
df[vec, ]
# [1] 2 1 3
```

Comment: bonus points for using row name indexing, but both solutions work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [match](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html) (and get rid of the NA values for elements in either vector for those that don't match in the other):

```
Filter(function(x) !is.na(x), match(rownames(df), vec))
```

Comment: actually, if you do match with nomatch=0, match will return 0 instead of NA for items that don't match.  Since the row select of [] just ignores 0s, you can just stick the match result directory into [], removing the need for the call to filter

Answer (score 1):

Since row name indexing also works on vectors, we can take this one step further and define:

```
'%ino%' <- function(x, table) {
    xSeq <- seq(along = x)
    names(xSeq) <- x
    Out <- xSeq[as.character(table)]
    Out[!is.na(Out)]
}
```

We now have the desired result:

```
df[rownames(df) %ino% vec, 1]
[1] 2 1 3
```

Inside the function, names() does an auto convert to character and table is changed with as.character(), so this also works correctly when the inputs to %ino% are numbers:

```
LETTERS[1:26 %in% 4:1]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"


LETTERS[1:26 %ino% 4:1]
[1] "D" "C" "B" "A"
```

Following %in%, missing values are removed:

```
LETTERS[1:26 %in% 3:-5]
[1] "A" "B" "C"

LETTERS[1:26 %ino% 3:-5]
[1] "C" "B" "A"
```

With %in% the logical sequence is repeated along the dimension of the object being subsetted, this is not the case with %ino%:

```
data.frame(letters, LETTERS)[1:5 %in% 3:-5,] 

    letters LETTERS
 1        a       A
 2        b       B
 3        c       C
 6        f       F
 7        g       G
 8        h       H
 11       k       K
 12       l       L
 13       m       M
 16       p       P
 17       q       Q
 18       r       R
 21       u       U
 22       v       V
 23       w       W
 26       z       Z


data.frame(letters, LETTERS)[1:5 %ino% 3:-5,]

   letters LETTERS
 3       c       C
 2       b       B
 1       a       A
```