# Renaming a few columns in a data frame: Why doesn't ifelse with %in% operator preserve order?

Tags: r

This is in reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10669726/419842).

I'd like to rename a subset of columns in a large data frame. I'd expect the following code to rename columns `X4`,`X5`,`X6` and `X7` to `gradek`, `grade1`, `grade2`, and `grade3` respectively:

```
set.seed(1)
in.df <- data.frame( matrix( rnorm(60), ncol=10) )
names(in.df) <- ifelse( names(in.df) %in% c('X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7'),
                         paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep=''),
                         names(in.df) )
```

However,

```
> names(in.df)
 [1] "X1"     "X2"     "X3"     "grade3" "gradek" "grade1" "grade2" "X8"    
 [9] "X9"     "X10"
```

even though

```
> paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep='')
[1] "gradek" "grade1" "grade2" "grade3"
```

showing that the order isn't preserved. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586652/r-preserve-order-when-using-matching-operators-in), suggests that using `match` instead of `%in%` would work, but in this case it does not. ( Perhaps that was true in other versions of R. In my installed version (2.15.3), the help page on `match` suggests that `%in%` is defined via `match` so switching it up would be of no help. )

Any help would be appreciated!

**Accepted answers** 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16111202/419842) fixes my renaming problem. 
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16111322/419842) explains the weird behavior is due to recycling.

Comment: I think it's because your yes condition isn't the same length as your no condition. Note the discussion of recycling in the docs.

Comment: I think you are right. Huh. I'll play with this a bit.

Comment: Why can't you just use something like `names(in.df)[names(in.df) %in% c("X4", "X5", "X6", "X7")] <- paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep='')`?

Comment: @AnandaMahto I was just about to post that as an answer...I think you should make that official.

Comment: @AnandaMahto That would work. I had previously tried `names(in.df[,c("X4", "X5", "X6", "X7")]) <- paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep='')` which doesn't. It hadn't occurred to me that what I need to subset was the call to `names` not the data frame itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%in%` should work, but perhaps `match` is better.

Consider the following. "A" and "B" represent your `names(in.df)`. We want to replace the values in "matchme" *in that order* using the results of `paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep='')`.

Compare the different output:

```
A <- B <- c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X9", "X10")
matchme <- c('X4', 'X7', 'X6', 'X5')
A[A %in% matchme] <- paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep='')
A
#  [1] "X1"     "X2"     "X3"     "gradek" "grade1" "grade2" "grade3" "X8"    
#  [9] "X9"     "X10"  
B[match(matchme, B)] <- paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep='')
B
#  [1] "X1"     "X2"     "X3"     "gradek" "grade3" "grade2" "grade1" "X8"    
#  [9] "X9"     "X10"
```

Comment: I don't understand your example. The `%in%` operator produces the correct order while the `match` function does not.

Comment: @NathanVanHoudnos It's because of the order in `matchme`. If you put those in the "right" order it will work the same.

Comment: @NathanVanHoudnos, read my preamble and why I'm suggesting `match`. My point is that I can specify order with `match` (replace X4 with gradek, x7 with grade1, and so on) but I can't do that with `%in%`.

Comment: I could have spent the time to think of a better example, but it's midnight where I am and I'm calling it a day :)

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that `matchme` permuted the order! I see the difference now. Thanks for your help. And get some sleep. :)

Answer (score 4):

[Ananda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16111202/892313) gives a good approach of how to do what you want. I will instead answer the question as to why you got the results you did rather than the ones you expected.

The reason the names seem out of order is related to how `ifelse` works and argument recycling.  Let's look at the three arguments to `ifelse`:

```
> list(names(in.df) %in% c('X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7'),
+      paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep=''),
+      names(in.df))
[[1]]
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

[[2]]
[1] "gradek" "grade1" "grade2" "grade3"

[[3]]
 [1] "X1"  "X2"  "X3"  "X4"  "X5"  "X6"  "X7"  "X8"  "X9"  "X10"
```

`ifelse` decides which corresponding element to pick based on whether the first argument is TRUE or FALSE. But the second argument is not as long as the first, so it is recycled to be the right length. Putting these into a data.frame so that looking at them side-by-side is easier, and manually expanding out the second set of names, gives:

```
> data.frame(test = names(in.df) %in% c('X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X7'),
+            `TRUE` = rep(paste('grade', c('k',1:3), sep=''),length=10),
+            `FALSE` = names(in.df))
    test  TRUE. FALSE.
1  FALSE gradek     X1
2  FALSE grade1     X2
3  FALSE grade2     X3
4   TRUE grade3     X4
5   TRUE gradek     X5
6   TRUE grade1     X6
7   TRUE grade2     X7
8  FALSE grade3     X8
9  FALSE gradek     X9
10 FALSE grade1    X10
```

So the 4th, 5th, 6th, and 7th elements of the new names are used, which correspond, due to argument recycling, to the 4th, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd.

Comment: Totally not a never mind! Thank you for answering the other part of my question. +1.

Comment: +1 - nice explanation going from `list` to `data.frame` to explain recycling